# Branch.io Apple Search Ads not appearing in Branch dashboard

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have been integrating the Branch SDK into my app to support mobile attribution. While I have followed the documentation outlined in https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/apple-search-ads, I am still not seeing test data appear in my Branch.io dashboard.

I have tested this on both the simulator and an actual device. For my actual device I registered it as a test device using Branch's Device ID app to ensure I had set the right IDFA tag.

Here is my AppDelegate code:

```swift
// Configure Branch
Branch.setUseTestBranchKey(true)

let instance = Branch.getInstance()
instance.delayInitToCheckForSearchAds()
instance.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: { params, error in 
    let searchAdDetails = BNCPreferenceHelper().appleSearchAdDetails
    if let searchAdDetails = searchAdDetails, let _ = (searchAdDetails["Version3.1"] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["iad-campaign-name"] {
        print("Got an Apple Search Ad Result:\n\(searchAdDetails)")
    }
})
```

I am able to verify the print statement "Got an Apple Search Ad..." is called, but I'm still not seeing anything appear in my Dashboard.

Here is what I have in my plist:

```
<key>branch_key</key>
<dict>
  <key>live</key>
  <string>{my_live_key}</string>
  <key>test</key>
  <string>{my_test_key}</string>
</dict>
```

Any ideas what steps could I be missing to make the test data appear in the dashboard? Thanks!

Comment: Just to rule it out the dumb question. If you check the built product does it have the keys you expect in the plist? I'm assuming you have some substitution going on as `{my_live_key}` is not the syntax for a standard Xcode substitution

Comment: Ah yes, `{my_live_key}` was just a placeholder for the purposes of my post. That wasn't the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue. Turns out the problem was a configuration on the Branch.io dashboard. I hadn't added the API certificates for the test environment (screenshot included of where this needed to go).

[image: Apple Search Ads on Branch dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have correctly imported the [AdService.framework](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/apple-search-ads#sdk-set-up-new-framework)?

If correctly integrated -

- You should see params like `iad-attribution` when you add
  `ignoreAppleSearchAdsTestData` to your staging app.
- you should be able to see the `apple_attribution_token` in the request body from the Branch SDK for the install or open. You can add
  `Branch.getInstance().enableLogging()` before initSession to see
  that.

Comment: Yep, I made sure to include the AdService framework.